# How override default Psr\LogLoggerInterface alias

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-4.2

I try to create an alias with id 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' for a service which implement this interface.
But the alias seems to not work.

Here is the my configuration in `services.yaml`

```
services:
    A\Name\Space\LoggerService:
        arguments:
            $arg1: ''
            $arg2: ''

    Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
        alias: A\Name\Space\LoggerService
```

This is how I try to get my service in my controller:

```
class SomeController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(LoggerInterface $logger): Response
    {
        $logger->info('index');
        return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

I expect to get a service with class `A\Name\Space\LoggerService` but I get the class `‌Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\Logger`.

If I get the service directly, it works well:

```
class SomeController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(\A\Name\Space\LoggerService $logger): Response
    {
        $logger->info('index');
        return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Finally, if I change my alias to:

```
logger:
    alias: A\Name\Space\LoggerService
```

it works well. But I don't want to override the Symfony logger service,  *only* the alias.

Comment: Why don't you use a decorator for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about **binding** like this one :

```
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            #...
            Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger: '@A\Name\Space\LoggerService'
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type

Comment: @GaëtanLickel are you sure? This only makes the alias available for services defined in the same file.

Comment: @igneus Yes I'm sure, it works well :) I get this service in the method params of a controller, and the class of this service is in the vendor